# Rota para páginas estáticas no MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, rotas

Estou com uma duvida na aplicação `ASP.Net MVC`:

**Estrutura**

```
Views
    |
    +-- Home
    |      |
    |      +-- Index.cshtml
    |      |
    |      +-- Page.cshtml
    |
    +-- Users
    |      |
    |      +-- Details.cshtml
    |
    +-- Paginas
    |      |
    |      +-- Pagina1.cshtml
    |      |
    |      +-- Pagina2.cshtml
    |
    +-- Shared
             |
             +-- Layout.cshtml
             |
             +-- _Partial.cshtml
```

Uma estrutura normal, porém a pasta "Paginas" não tem nenhuma controller que faz a associação. Nesta pasta eu vou colocar todas as páginas que são "Html Statics".
Ou seja se eu criar um novo arquivo "Pagina3.cshtml" e colocar nesta pasta, e quando acessar a url `{local}\paginas\Pagina3` apareça o conteúdo desta página, mas quando eu faço isto retorna um erro 404.

Só não quero criar arquivos `.html` pela fato de utilizar o `Layout.cshtml`.

Comment: Crie um controller padrão para lidar com esses arquivos estáticos

Comment: Usar páginas *realmente* estáticas (HTML mesmo) está fora de questão?

Comment: @AndreCalil o problema de eu utilizar páginas estáticas, é que não vou conseguir utilizar o Layout.cshtml

Comment: @Tiago: Utilize o método `HandleUnknownAction` da forma que indiquei na minha resposta... esse método existe para esse propósito.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

De acordo com a estrutura que você enviou, você vai precisar fazer um sub-roteamento num controller "Paginas".

> O parâmetro "id" é necessário caso você não queira alterar a rota default:
>   {controller}/{action}/{id}

```
namespace MyDynamicRoutingApp.Controllers
{
    public class PaginasController : Controller
    {
        //
        // GET: /Paginas/pagina/{id}
        // Exemplo: /Paginas/pagina/pagina1
        // Exemplo: /Paginas/pagina/pagina2....
        public ActionResult Pagina(string id)
        {
            return View(id);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Alan funcionou, apenas alterei o nome do método de Pages para Pagina...obrigado

Comment: Só é interessante você além disso fazer um tratamento e retornar 404 se a página requisitada não existir.

Answer (score 1):

Pra que a rota funcione corretamente, você precisaria ter um `PaginasController`, sendo cada método deste controller apontando para uma página das suas Views:

```cs
namespace SeuProjeto.Controllers
{
    public class PaginasController : Controller
    {
        public ViewResult Pagina1() {
            Return View();
        }

        public ViewResult Pagina2() {
            Return View();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Certo, mas toda vez que eu criar uma página nova, terei que criar um metodo novo também. Não queria realizar este procedimento, só gostaria de adicionar estas páginas de conteúdo, sem tem que alterar alguma controller

Comment: Não tem como. Não é assim que o MVC trabalha.

Comment: Se a página é estática, não precisa de um método pra cada um não, basta criar um mapa url vs página a ser mostrada e criar um único controller, como `StaticController` com um método `ViewResult servStatic(String viewName)`

Answer (score 0):

A forma de fazer isso é usando o método [`virtual HandleUnknownAction`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.controller.handleunknownaction%28v=vs.118%29.aspx) da classe `Controller` da qual todos os controlers derivam. O exemplo a seguir, renderiza qualquer página cujo `cshtml` exista na pasta de views correspondente ao controller:

```
public class StaticController : Controller
{
    protected override void HandleUnknownAction(string actionName)
    {
        try
        {
            this.View(actionName).ExecuteResult(this.ControllerContext);
        }
        catch
        {
            this.HttpNotFound("A página requisitada não existe.")
                .ExecuteResult(this.ControllerContext);
        }
    }
}
```

Agora, quaisquer views que você criar dentro da pasta `\View\Static\` serão renderizadas ao chamar o controller, com um nome de action qualquer... e caso a view não exista, será retornado um 404.

Você pode usar todos os recursos nas views, página de Layout, pode usar um model (desde que você passe um no método do controller).

[image: Action QualquerPagina, que não existe no controller]

Note que as actions `Index` e `QualquerPagina` não estão declaradas no `StaticController`, e ainda assim vão funcionar.

**P.S.** só pra constar, minha configuração de rotas está assim:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "Default",
    url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
    defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
);

routes.MapRoute(
    name: "Home",
    url: "{action}/{id}",
    defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
);
```